# add row after each subtotal excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, subtotal

I need a macro that will insert a row after each subtotal, please see picture below for desired result.

[image: Added rows highlighted]

Comment: Good for you! Are you asking permission or did you have a specific question regarding the code you've already written?

Comment: @Jeeped - that's the coolest I've heard anyone put it in a while :D

Comment: @E.Villiger- Even for a holiday Saturday this has to be one of the whiniest, laziest, self-entitled questions I've encountered in quite a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 1000 to 1 Step -1 ' adjust 1000 to the row number of the last element
    If Cells(i,1).Font.Bold And Cells(i,1) <> "" then
        Cells(i+1,1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You might want to work from the bottom up.

Comment: True, I guess it would be more solid that way, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Always work from the bottom up when inserting or deleting rows. If not, when deleting you risk 'skipping over' rows during iteration and when inserting, you are artificially extending your range with the newly inserted rows.